# Use @ user variables inside mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have this long query which I must run inside a loop. I prepared it as follows:

```
    $stmt = $db2->prepare("
    select 
        sum(n_pallets) as n_pallets,
        taxa_pallet,
        sum(valor_pallets) as valor_pallets 
    from 
        ( select 
            A.id_order, A.n_notafiscal, 
            @1:= case 
                when C.tipo_palet like 'A' then D.PalA 
                when C.tipo_palet like 'B' then D.PalB 
                when C.tipo_palet like 'C' then D.PalC 
                when C.tipo_palet like 'D' then D.PalD 
                else E.cs_pallet 
            end as cases_pallet,
            G.taxa_pallet,
            @2 := ceil(B.quantidade/@1) as n_pallets,
            G.taxa_pallet*@2 as valor_pallets
          from 
            lop_order A inner join 
            lop_order_item B using (cod_fatura) inner join 
            lop_cliente C using (cod_cliente) inner join 
            deposito H using (cod_deposito) inner join 
            produto D using (cod_produto) left join 
            lop_cli_prod_pal E on 
                (E.cod_cliente=C.cod_cliente and 
                 E.cod_produto=D.cod_produto) inner join 
            lop_transportador F on (F.cod_transportador= ? ) inner join 
            lop_lead_time G on 
                (F.cod_transportador=G.cod_transportador and 
                 A.cod_domicilio_fiscal=G.cod_domicilio_fiscal and 
                 H.cidade=G.cidade_origem and H.UF=G.UF_origem and 
                 G.data_inicial_vigencia<=A.data_nf and 
                 G.data_final_vigencia>=A.data_nf)
          where
            A.tipo_order='E' and 
            A.tipo_usage<>'ZTRANS' and 
            A.id_order= ?
        ) as pal 
    group by id_order, n_notafiscal");

$id_order = '';
$cod_transportador_pallet = '';
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $id_order,$cod_transportador_pallet);
```

Notice the @1 and @2 user variables, used do calculate values inside the query. This query works fine outside PHP, provided that I replace the ?'s with data.

Inside the loop, I do:

```
    // (...)
    $id_order=XXX; // some data
    $cod_transportador_pallet=XXX; // some data
    // (...)
    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        $erro .= htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)."<br>\n";
        continue;
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($n_pallets,$valor_pallet,$valor_calculado);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $erro .= "$n_pallets, $valor_pallet, $valor_calculado<br>\n";
```

I get no execution error here, but the three result variables will be set to 0,'' and 0, no matter what i set on the two binded variables. I am wondering if this is caused by the use of "@" inside the prepared statement, any clue?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thats a huge statement! :D

Comment: it's $mysqli->error, nor $stmt->error

Comment: no, it's not. Check at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, you use $stmt->error to get the execution error - see example #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guys, since I could not find a solution for this problem, I just gave up with the prepared statement and created a stored procedure with the same code. Not the solution I wanted, but at least it works! Anyway, thanks for reading!